# Delete unapplied migrations Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I modified a model field in my local environment and made the migrations. Every thing seemed fine until I pushed it to production. I tried to apply the migrations to my DB and received an error:

**cannot ALTER TABLE because it has pending trigger events**

I ended up just reverting to the previous migration, which solved the problem for now.

But now I have these unapplied migration files pending and I need to find a way to either delete them or ignore them. What is the best solution moving forward?

[Local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvqed.png)

[Production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOkvv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fake the problematic migration ([documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake)) - and then run the rest of the migrations.

Should be:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake 000x_problematic_migration
```

And then run the rest of the migrations

```
python manage.py migrate
```